# What is the max speed of Magento?Or GTMETRIX wrong?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a magento site.I checked it at gtmetrix and it was about 20% both Pagespeed and Yslow.
Now i increased in every possible way you cant say an option that i have not used yet.
You can check it at:

http://gtmetrix.com/reports/modernmarkt.com/eYBgKmtj

And its still wait same change being propogated.Its better than facebook's but the site is still very very very slow surfing between categoires and products.

If you check this site:

http://gtmetrix.com/reports/homesatelit.eu/qYXmXD96

You can see it shows worst even at page load speed but this is is fast as light surfing on it.This sit not use magento.

Also at Gtmetrix you can check the top1000 site and some has about 30% and 90s page load speed but still fast as light.

It seems to me that gtmetrix is useless and to recommends and statics arent count on the real/actual page speed as if you check facebook has a very bad 34%

I've spent a week and money to increase my static and now it seems its not count.
But if its not than what?
What should do?Is there anything i can do?
I use cloud server hosting.

I learn a lot in the past weeks and if you can help figure it out i would write down everything that should be known about Magento speed optimization.

Comment: do not use gtmetrix to test anything, use http://www.webpagetest.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize in three ways,

```
1.Frontend Optimization
 - Js and CSS caching
 - CDN for media files
 - Browser caching

2.Server Level Caching

  - Enable APC
  - Enable Varnish
  - Use Full page cache module in Magento

3.Data level caching

  - Sessions using Redis (module already  available in Magento 1.9 +)
  - Memcache for mysql caching
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various way to optimize a website, Optimizing Magento is as much about patience as it is about programming. Always tweak and test your sites speed after every change that you make.

1)Magento requires dedicated hosting in most cases (Stores where you have a lot of products and categories).
2)Make sure your server has a sufficient amount of RAM to support your site.
3)Combine and minify your JS and CSS files. 
4)Turn on Compilation (test this on a dev enviroment first). 
5)Turn on Flat Data. 
6)Use an External Cache like Redis or Varnish. 
7)Make Sure you either have Zend Op cache enabled or APC. 
8)Make sure GZIP is enabled. 
9)Turn off logging on Production(This may seem a bit risky but logging data takes time)
10)Lazy Load certain common components on your pages

In addition to GTmetrics als use pageSpeed insights by Google and Pingdoms Website speed test. 
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ 
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/